# Does dart code of a different `@pragma(vm:entry-point)` runs in a separate isolate?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates, dart-vm

I have been working with Flutter and I have a doubt.
I am trying to show overlay on top of my screen. That's why I am using [flutter_overlay_window](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window)

In its [example](https://github.com/Adora-Inc/flutter_overlay_window/blob/6bcbfadbc35a0cd2bb8be155afead14451c98d5d/example/lib/main.dart#L5) code I found this

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

@pragma("vm:entry-point")
void overlayMain() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TrueCallerOverlay(),
    ),
  );
}
```

`main` is the main `entrypoint` of dart VM's root isolate. But what about the overlayMain entry point?

How does the dart code inside of this entry point gets executed? In a new isolate or the same isolate?

Another question, will it be in the same flutter engine or different flutter engine.

I know the meaning of `@pragma(vm:entry-point)` notation.

These are additional readings I did. I have read a lot but didn't get any satisfactory answer

1. [dart vm](https://mrale.ph/dartvm/)
2. [dart executor](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/dart/DartExecutor.html)
3. [Flutter engine](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/FlutterEngine.html)
4. [Dart isolates](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/main/runtime/dart_isolate.h#L63)

Please share any additional resources that I might have missed.

Comment: https://github.com/X-SLAYER/flutter_overlay_window/blob/main/android/src/main/java/flutter/overlay/window/flutter_overlay_window/FlutterOverlayWindowPlugin.java

Referring this Line 125. It will indeed create a new Engine all together. @pragma is just used to create a top level function that can be referred from native code. Referring this :https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Launch-Flutter-with-non-main-entrypoint

Comment: Yes I have seen that. This is plug-in-specific code that needs to render a flutterView, hence to attach it you need a flutterEngine. My question is however a bit more general as in, does the code inside any`@pragma("vm:entry-point")` gets executed in a separate isolate!

Comment: It is a compiler directive. It tells the compiler that the function should be included in the library/executable even if the compiler optimizations wouldn't let it be compiled because it thinks it is unnecessary. It has nothing to do with isolates